# Uploading files from React

Tags: reactjs, express, multer

I would like to upload files using a React client and express with multer package as a file server.
Here is what I have:

The React client

```
import { useState } from "react";

const UploadForm = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const uploadImages = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    const imageFiles = evt.target.files;
    const uploadImage = async (img) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", img);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:3002/admin/uploadImage",
          {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "no-cors",
            body: formData,
          }
        );

        console.log("response", response);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      }
    };
    Array.from(imageFiles).map((image) => {
      uploadImage(image);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={uploadImages} multiple accept="image/*" />
      <span>Drag files here!</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadForm;
```

The Express server

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter }).single("image"));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));

app.use("/admin", adminRoutes);

app.listen(3002);
```

And the admin routes inside the routes/admin.js file

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/uploadImage", (req, res, next) => {
  const image = req.file;
  if (!image) {
    return res.status(422);
  }

  const imageUrl = image.path;
  console.log(imageUrl);
  res.send(imageUrl);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Images are actually saved into the `images` destination folder but I don't get the image url as a response.  Inside my React client `response.ok` is always `false`.
What am I missing ?

Comment: I might be wrong: You are appending `image` to formdata that gets passed along to the server. But in your admin route you check for `req.file`. Should this be `req.image`?

Comment: app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter }).single("image")); the image upload is working, but I don't get the response back

Comment: Yeah, but then in your `admin/uploadImage`-route you get the `req.file`, and if does not exist you return an `422` error. Do you see the `console.log(imageUrl)` from this route in your server console?

Comment: Yes I see the value of imageUrl in the console.  But I don't have it in the Response on the client side if I check response.text() for example

Comment: I changed library, now I am using axios and it is working fine.